# Op execution only when needed?

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say I have some var `v`, and some op `increase_op = tf.assign_add(v, 1)` in the computation graph, but then I do `session.run` for some unrelated op/tensor which does not depend on `increase_op` nor has it in any control dependencies.

- Can I be sure that it will not execute `increase_op` then?
- I.e. TensorFlow will always only execute an op if it is needed and don't do any speculative execution?
- Will `increase_op` in the computation graph have any other side effects, like e.g. pre-allocating some memory (e.g. assume instead `tf.assign_add(v, some_very_big_thing)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I be sure that it will not execute increase_op then?

Yes.

> I.e. TensorFlow will always only execute an op if it is needed and don't do any speculative execution?

Yes, most tensorflow programs rely on this kind of graph pruning for correctness so any change to this will have to be careful.

> Will increase_op in the computation graph have any other side effects, like e.g. pre-allocating some memory (e.g. assume instead tf.assign_add(v, some_very_big_thing))?

If `some_very_big_thing` is a tf.constant then it will use up RAM permanently, but if it's a Tensor produced from another computation you will be fine.